# How to make a single column editable in Visual Force?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am using visual force to show the parent and child at a single table. Now I want to make a child column editable. When I click on Class Notes Only the first row is editable but another row is not editable and the saves method is not working correctly.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" controller="StudentListView" id="thePage" showHeader="true">
    <apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!scheduleClasses}" var="parent" id="theTable">
        <apex:column value="{!parent.Instructor__r.Name}" />
        <apex:column value="{!parent.Start_Date__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!parent.End_Date__c}" />
        <apex:column value="{!parent.Duration_In_Hour__c}" />
        <apex:column headerValue="Topic">
            <apex:outputText value="{!parent.Class_Track_Name__r.Name}" />
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!parent.Note__c}" />
        
        <apex:column >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!classAttendanceList}" var="attendance">
                <apex:column headerValue="Student Name">
                    <apex:outputText value="{!attendance.Student__r.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Time/Day of the session">
                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}"> 
                        <apex:param value="{!attendance.Class_Start_Date__c}" />
                    </apex:outputText>
                    <apex:outputText value=" - " />
                    <apex:outputText value="{!attendance.Class_Start_Time__c}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="saveButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick"/>
                <apex:column value="{!attendance.Class_Notes__c}" />
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons > 
        <apex:commandButton value="Edit" action="{!save}" id="editButton" />
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="saveButton" />
    </apex:pageBlockButtons> 
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>

public with sharing class StudentListView {
    List<Scheduled_Class__c> scheduleClasses {get; set;}
    List<Attendance__c> classAttendanceList {get; set;}

    public String currentRecordId {get;set;}

    public List<Scheduled_Class__c> getScheduleClasses() {
        currentRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
        if (scheduleClasses == null) {
            scheduleClasses = [SELECT Id, Instructor__r.Name, Note__c, Duration__c, FORMAT(Start_Date__c), FORMAT(Start_Time__c), End_Date__c, End_Time__c, Duration_In_Hour__c, Class_Track_Name__r.Name, (SELECT Id, Student_Name__c, Student_Status__c, Course_Status__c FROM Class_Attendances__r) FROM Scheduled_Class__c WHERE Id = :currentRecordId];
        }
        return scheduleClasses;
    }

    public List<Attendance__c> getClassAttendanceList() {
        if (classAttendanceList == null) {
            currentRecordId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
            classAttendanceList = [SELECT Id, Instructor_Name__c, Student_Name__c, Class_Notes__c, FORMAT(Class_End_Date__c), FORMAT(Class_Start_Date__c), Class_Start_Time__c, Student__r.Name, Class_End_Time__c FROM Attendance__c WHERE Scheduled_Class__r.Id = :currentRecordId];
        }
        return classAttendanceList;
    }
    public Pagereference save() {
        try{
            update classAttendanceList;
            return ApexPages.CurrentPage();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```